# Well-known American figure with Roman numerals

Tags: word, language, english, history

Which well-known American figure has an 8-letter name, with 6 consonants and all of them are Roman numerals?

Comment: 'and all of those consonants'?

Answer (score 38):

I suspect it might be

> MaLCoLM X

Comment: I'm not sure spaces count as roman numerals...

Comment: @beppe9000 They don't need to. This answer fulfills every condition of the question: It has 8 letters. It has 6 consonants, and all of _those consonants_ are Roman numerals. Please note that "a" and "o" are not Roman numerals.

Comment: @only_pro Whoops, my bad.

Answer (score 4):

> Melville (as in Moby Dick author)  is close (5 consonants and 1 vowel that are roman numerals, 8 letter name)

Answer (score 4):

Alternative Answer

> Grace **McCallum** who is a well-known [American gymnast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_McCallum)

Answer (score 3):

<sub>This is not, strictly, an answer, but …</sub>

Six? 
You only want six?

> If you ignore the middle initial,
> $\text{Cecil}~\color{gray}{\text{B.}}~\text{DeMille}$

has twelve letters, of which all ***seven*** consonants are Roman numerals.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly (but more cheekily) close is:

> A. LINCoLN

**Note:** N was used (at least once) as a roman numeral representing nulla, the Latin word for 0! ;)

Comment: Last time I checked, N wasn't a Roman numeral...?! I only see 3 (standard) Roman numeral consonants here... (I'm guessing you're using N for 'Nulla', zero...) (Actually that's quite nice lateral thinking - removing my downvote...!)

Comment: @Stiv Indeed! It's a  stretch but I saw this... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Zero